# Проблема с Runtime.getRuntime().exec() Java

Tags: java, cmd, компиляция, exec

Пытаюсь запустить команду для командной строки с помощью Runtime.getRuntime().exec.

Вот собственно команда
"cmd /C cd C:\Scripts && javac Main.java && java Main"

Вот код всего класса

```
package sample;

import java.io.*;

public class Executor {

    private String path;
    private String className;
    private String extension;
    private String command;

    boolean saveClassString;

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

    public Executor(String extension, String path, String className){
        this.extension = extension;
        this.path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
        this.className = className;
    }

    void start()throws Exception{
        command = Main.programSettings.getCommandMap().get(extension).replaceAll("%%", className); 
        command = command.replaceAll("##", path); //"cmd /C cd ## && javac %%.java && java %%" 
        System.out.println(command);
        readData(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }

    private void readData(Process run) throws Exception {
        String line;

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader outputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        inputReader.close();
        while ((line = outputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        outputReader.close();
        run.waitFor();
    }
```

При запуске выдает следущее:

```
cmd /C cd C:\Scripts && javac Main.java && java Main  //System.out.print()
javac: file not found: Main.java                   // это уже от Runtime
Usage: javac <options> <source files>              //
use -help for a list of possible options           //

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Этот класс должен компилировать Файл и вывести на экран результат работы скомпилированного файла, но он это отказывается делать.
Если вызывать команду "cmd /C cd C:\Scripts && javac Main.java && java Main" через командную строку, то получается ответ как и при запуске сверху. Если запустить в командной строке команду без "cmd /c" то команда сработает успешно, файл скомпилируется и выведет результат работы, однако runtime.getruntime.exec() отказывается принимать команду без "cmd /c" (вылетает с ошибкой).
Пробовал и сохранять команду в bat файл и передавать ProcessBuilder, однако ничего не выходит. Еще большее смятение вызывает то, что в предыдущем проекте я использовал такую же команду и все работало. 
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Располагается файл C:\Scripts\Main.java

Comment: Здесь javac ругается на отсутствие Main.java в папке, всё остальное выглядит правильно.

Comment: Парадокс состоит в том, что Main.java в папке есть. Я создал новый проект, в котором вызываю эту команду "cmd /C cd C:\Scripts && javac Main.java && java Main" через exec, и все работает, однако в этой программе почему- то отказывается. Код для запуска процесса и чтения данных из него в обоих программах абсолютно одинаков.

Comment: Не знаю почему у вас не получается, с программной точки зрения всё верно - это доказывает первый проект, поэтому могу только дать пару догадок: Возьмите Main.java в кавычки и попробуйте получить путь к директории `cd` или `echo %cd%`, а также файлы `dir`.

Comment: Похоже runtime.exec() по каким-то причинам отказывался менять директорию. Я запустил команду "cmd /c javac C:\Scripts\Main.java && java C:\Scripts\Main" и файл скомпилировался, однако появилась другая проблема, скомпилированный файл отказывается запускаться (выдает ошибку "Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Scripts\Main") Можете помочь решить эту проблему? Я прочитал про установку системной переменной CLASSPATH и про ключ -cp для запуска, однако я не понял как правильно их проставить.

Comment: Попробуйте `java -cp "путь к папке в кавычках" Main`

Comment: Все равно не хочет работать: "cmd /c javac C:\Scripts\Main.java && java -cp "C:\Scripts" C:\Scripts\Main"
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Scripts\Main  ( Может я не правильно указал путь -cp?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85890/discussion-between-0x666c-and-antonidas).